# ¿Como crear base de datos con 2 archivos .mdf y .ldf con sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola tengo que crear una base de datos con archivos .mdf y ldf, pero me sale error hice esto:

```
CREATE DATABASE Producto

ON(NAME='Producto_Data',
   FILENAME='D:\Users\Usuario\SQL\prod1.mdf',
   SIZE= 20MB,
   MAXSIZE = 20480KB ,   
   NAME='Producto_Dataa',
   FILENAME='D:\Users\Usuario\SQL\prod2.mdf',
   SIZE= 20MB,
   MAXSIZE = 10240KB ,
   FILEGROWTH = 10% 
   )
   LOG ON(NAME='Producto_Log',
   FILENAME= 'D:\Users\Usuario\SQL\prod3.ldf',
   SIZE= 5MB,
   MAXSIZE = 10240KB ,   
   FILEGROWTH = 10%,
   NAME='Producto_Logg',
   FILENAME= 'D:\Users\Usuario\SQL\prod4.ldf',
   SIZE= 5MB,
   FILEGROWTH = 0 , 
   MAXSIZE = 10240KB,    
   FILEGROWTH = 10% )
```

El error que me sale es:
Invalid usage of the option NAME in the Create/Alter Database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En sql server solo puede haber un archivo principal de datos "mdf", y varios secundarios normalmente sugeridos mediante la extensión "ndf"

[Archivos y grupos de archivos](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-files-and-filegroups?view=sql-server-ver15)

Otra cosas a tener en cuenta, son el uso de carpetas "susceptibles", de tener problemas de acceso, como son las carpetas de usuario, porque quien intentará acceder a ellas, será el motor bajo la cuenta en la que se ejecute el servicio, y pueden estar restringidas. No creo que sea el sitio adecuado para situar los archivos de una base de datos.

Y tampoco parece razonable crear una base de datos, con un tamaño inicial cuyo valor máximo de crecimiento sea exactamente el mismo tamaño, por tanto no podrá crecer, cuando le indicas que puede ir creciendo un 10%

Además es recomendable trabajar con la misma unidad de medida. Si expresas parte de los datos en KB, todos deberían de ser en KB.

Ahora bien, el primer error que te muestra, es porque le estás dando dos nombres lógicos a un solo archivo físico.

```
CREATE DATABASE Producto

ON(
   NAME='Producto_Data',
   FILENAME='D:\temp\prod1.mdf',
   SIZE= 10240KB,
   MAXSIZE = 20480KB ,   
   FILEGROWTH = 10% 
   ),(
   NAME='Producto_Dataa',
   FILENAME='D:\temp\prod2.ndf',
   SIZE= 10240KB,
   MAXSIZE = 20480KB ,
   FILEGROWTH = 10% 
   )
   LOG ON(
   NAME='Producto_Log',
   FILENAME= 'D:\temp\prod3.ldf',
   SIZE= 5120KB,
   MAXSIZE = 10240KB ,   
   FILEGROWTH = 10%
   ),(
   NAME='Producto_Logg',
   FILENAME = 'D:\temp\prod4.ldf',
   SIZE= 5120KB,
   MAXSIZE = 10240KB,    
   FILEGROWTH = 10%
   )
```

Te he cambiado los valores iniciales del mdf y ndf para que tengan un posible crecimiento.

Comment: Muchas Gracias funciono :D , Saludos!